# find_elements_by_xpath() not producing the desired output python selenium scraping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to find a `tr` by its class of `.tableOne`. Here is my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
cells = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tableone"]')
```

But the output of the `cells` variable is `[]`, an empty array.

Here is the html of the page:

```
<tbody class="tableUpper">
    <tr class="tableone">
        <td><a class="studentName" href="//www.abc.com"> student one</a></td>
        <td><a href="//www.abc.com/overview"> <span class="id_one"></span> <span class="long">Place</span> <span class="short">Place</span></a></td>
        <td class="hide-s">
            <span class="state"></span> <span class="studentState">student_state</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hello @Praveen, could you include the html in your post as text instead of using a image? Also one thought, it might be because you need to wait for the page to load before getting elements off it but I'm not really familiar with selenium so I can't really say that's defiantly the problem.

Comment: <tbody class="tableUpper">
    <tr class="tableone">
     <td><a class="studentName" href="//www.abc.com">
       student one</a></td>
     <td><a href="//www.abc.com/overview">
       <span class="id_one"></span>
       <span class="long">Place</span>
       <span class="short">Place</span></a>
     </td>
     <td class="hide-s"><span class="state"></span>
      <span class="studentState">student_state</span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
    <tr class="tableone">..</tr>
   </tbody>

Comment: There is problem with editing the question, I am working in it, since I am new to this site, I have some troubles

Comment: Ah, that's ok I've just edited your question so If you accept my edit I've put the code inline

Comment: Thankyou for editing the code, I have approved it. Hope to see the answer soon

Comment: It should work. Are you able to capture any other element value? try 'elements_by_class_name'

Comment: @Praveen What exactly do you mean by _...find a `tr` by its class..._? What is your exact _usecase_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to get 'Student one', 'Place', 'Studednt State', for all tehe tr elements

Comment: @NavinRawat It only produce an empty set []

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import re

cells = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'tr') and contains(@class, 'tableone')]")

for (e in cells):
    insides = e.find_elements_by_xpath("./td")
    for (i in insides):
        result = re.search('\">(.*)</', i.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
        print result.group(1)
```

What this does is gets all the `tr` elements that have class `tableone`, then iterates through each element and lists all the `tds`. Then iterates through the outerHTML of each `td` and strips each string to get the text value.
It's quite unrefined and will return empty strings, I think. You might need to put some more work into the final product.